# Looking for a specific jquery carousel

Tags: jquery, slider, carousel

I have been scouring the net for 2 days now and can't find a jquery carousel taht meets my demands.

What I want is a normal infinite carousel, with left and right navigation links, but I want one of the images (the main image) [an image currently in focus] to be twice as big and aligned to the right.

The closest I could get was with the lemmon slider
You can check my attempts here:
[demo of what I got so far](http://jalokimgraphics.pl/demo.html)

I thank in advance for any help.

Cheers

Comment: Some inspirations: http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/01/jquery-carousel.html

Comment: Your demo seems to align large image to the left, not right...

Comment: Yeah thats also part of my problem :P it needs to be on the right. Thanks for the help. I might be able to get my effect with the examples you guys provided thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [content flow](http://www.jacksasylum.eu/ContentFlow/).  You can easily change it around to fit your needs.  Take a look at the addon section for help as to how to do this.  There is one in there for the carousel, and also one showing how to add a large image.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

A good start to do your own style should be this webpage: http://web.enavu.com/tutorials/making-a-jquery-infinite-carousel-with-nice-features/

It should be helpfull enough.